# How to use useState and useEffect over array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the code below, I have a few textareas where the user should input jsons.

I tried to use and array (well, object with numeric keys, just for the ease from rest operator assignment), and I also wanted to avoid parsing both JSONs at every change of either.

It works well, except that for the first render, I get validation only on the second json. I am pretty sure it comes down to scope, with old values being stored in the useEffect, but I added the callback versions of setErrors and that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the right pattern for this?

PS: I intend to move each textarea into individual components of course, but would like to understand what is wrong here first.

```js
  const [jsons, setJsons] = useState<{ [k: number]: string }>({ 0: '', 1: '' });
  const [containers, setContainers] = useState<{ [k: number]: object }>({ 0: {}, 1: {} });
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<{ [k: number]: string }>({ 0: '', 1: '' });

  const useContainerEffect = (index: number) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      let container = {};
      try {
        container = JSON.parse(jsons[index]);
        setErrors(() => ({ ...errors, [index]: '' }))
      } catch (e) {
        setErrors(() => ({ ...errors, [index]: VALUE_IS_NOT_JSON }))
      }
      setContainers(() => ({ ...containers, [index]: container }))

    }, [jsons[index]]);
  }

  useContainerEffect(0);
  useContainerEffect(1);

  const jsonInputChange = (e: HTMLTextAreaElement, i: number) => {
    setJsons({ ...jsons, [i]: e.value })
  }
```

Comment: You propably want to use useCallback instead of useEffect in this scenario, if you could setup codesandbox with example above then I can help you out

Comment: For any state variable such as: `const [abc, setAbc] = useState();`, there are two ways to use `setAbc`. First, by directly assigning some value such as `setAbc('some value');`. Another, by manipulating the existing value - such as: `setAbc(prev => (prev + ' abc'));`. If one does not need to use the existing value (ie, `prev`), I'm quite unsure why one may require `setAbc(() => {...some commands...});`.

Comment: @jsN00b Ah, that makes sense, I tried it but the problem as unaffected.

Comment: @jsN00b You were right. I previously switched to this form, but still used the value in the external scope. Your solution works (also in Clarity's answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [functional form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `useState` to set your errors. Also it's a good practice not to use complex dependencies in dependency array, so they can be statically checked:

```
  const useContainerEffect = (index: number) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      let container = {};
      try {
        container = JSON.parse(jsons[index]);
        setErrors((err) => ({ ...err, [index]: '' }));
      } catch (e) {
        setErrors((err) => ({ ...err, [index]: 'VALUE_IS_NOT_JSON' }));
      }
      setContainers(() => ({ ...containers, [index]: container }));
    }, [index]);
  };
```

Comment: Agree on the functional form, I just had tried the other form when I couldn't figure out the error. But it still happens.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point, it might happen. TBH in this case I'd just use `index` as dependency and not the `jsons[index]`, since the code reacts to the index change and not the specific property of that object. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I used the right form, but didn't take the passed values! Thanks!

Comment: It works now! Outstanding. I was looking at things so wrong in terms of scope! Thanks a bunch!